# How to define CSS anchor text decoration for anchors in a specific container

Tags: css

Say i have this:

```
#mytopbar {
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #000000;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
```

Howeever, I am unhappy about the general hover/visit anchor text decoration. How can I override text decoration so links are underlined for a specific ID? (not class)

Do I have to supply style on each anchor tag, or can I somehow do it in CSS? I have tried things like `#mytopbar a {...}` and `#mytopbar a:hover {...}` but it does not work as I hoped.

Comment: How did `#mytopbar a` (...etc) *not* 'work as you hoped'? What did it do instead? Anything, nothing..?

Comment: A demo or JSFiddle is very welcom!

Comment: Put some html or a Fiddler, so people can see what you want.

Comment: @David it simply did not have any effect, e.g. underlining anchors. (But I have accepted an answer now and upvoted rest of answers and comments as thanks for trying to help!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS sound like it getting overwriten try this.

```
 #mytopbar a:hover { text-decoration : underline !important;}
```

Comment: This style the id class and not an anchor

Comment: I ended up solving the problem in a different way, but I agree to the problem cause. (I was editing a theme for a website that contained a ton of CSS.)

Answer (score 2):

```
#mytopbar a:hover {
   text-decoration: underline;
}
a {
   text-decoration: none;
}
```

Be default, links will not have an underlined (regular and those hovered over). Only links within #mytopbar will be underline on hover